# Нужно настроить приоритет запуска элемента приложения в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Такой вопрос - в моем приложении блок Google Ads грузится только через 3-4 минуты после запуска.
Как сделать приоритет запуска, чтобы блок загружался за пару секунд, а потом все остальное??
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.usa.news.twenty.four.seven
Приложение